# Getting NullpointerException in JDBC code

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

The following code is throwing a NullPointerException - I don't know where the problem is. I am using an Excel spreadsheet as a backend.

```
//actionlistener for btnfetch
btnfetch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        try
        {
            String name="";
            d1 = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(textdate.getText());
            java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d1.getTime());
            java.sql.Date sqld=null;

            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from [ARNUM$]");
            String getname=null;

            while(rs.next())
            {
                getname=rs.getString(1);
                sqld=rs.getDate(2);

                System.out.println(getname+"  "+sqld+"  "+sqlDate);

                if(sqlDate.compareTo(sqld)==0)
                {  
                    name=name+"  "+getname;
                    name=name.toUpperCase();
                }
                System.out.println(name);

            }


            if(name.length()==0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    pnlp4,
                    "No Name having "+textdate.getText(),
                    "Warning",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
                );
            }
            else
            {
                textname.setText(name);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end actionPerformed
}); //end addActionListener
```

Comment: Which line is the exception on?

Answer (score 0):

The field value of `sqld` might be null. Now unfortunately `sqlDate.compareTo(null)` will throw a NullPointerException. *(Other compareTo's behave better.)*